# Implement chat functionality in iPhone application in IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xmppframework

I want to implement chat functionality in iPhone application. Please suggest me. Can we use xmppframework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation:

you can download the framework from here

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout using a mercurial client for your OS.

or

download files individually from

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/

After this use

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone

to install the sdk

For the mercurial client:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads

Usage:

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/IntroToFramework offers some good instructions on use

Comment: All above links are not working..can you please pur correct links?

Comment: Can you please check "xmpp framework" in "google code". You'll get it. I have checked it. Looks like all the code locations are changed So links are not working as of now.